# "Reloading" a file in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, require, reload

In Node.JS, I'm trying to "reload" a file. I have the following code:

```
  delete require.cache[require.resolve("./pathToFile/" + restartModule)]
```

with `restartModule` being the file name, but I'm not sure how I could add the file back using `require()` and define it as the variable `restartModule`. For example, if `restartModule` is `myModule`, how would I add `myModule.js` into the var called `myModule`? Or maybe there's an easier way to simply "reload" a file in the cache?

Answer (score 4):

You could do something simple enough like this:

```
function reloadModule(moduleName){
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(moduleName)]
    console.log('reloadModule: Reloading ' + moduleName + "...");
    return require(moduleName)
}

var restartModule= reloadModule('./restartModule.js');
```

You would have to call reloadModule every time you want to reload the source though. You could simplify by wrapping like:

```
var getRestartModule = function() {
    return reloadModule('./restartModule.js');
} 

getRestartModule().doStuff();
```

Or

```
var reloadModules = function() {
    return {
        restartModule = reloadModule('./restartModule.js');
    };
}

var modules = reloadModules();
modules.restartModule.doStuff();
```

Or:

```
var reloadModules = function(moduleList) {
    var result = {};
    moduleList.forEach((module) => {
        result[module.name] = reloadModule(module.path);
    });
}
var modules = reloadModules([{name: 'restartModule', path: './restartModule.js'}]);

modules.restartModule.doStuff();
```

You could even put the module reload on a setInterval so modules would get loaded every N seconds.

Then there's always nodemon: https://nodemon.io/ this is useful in development, whenever a source file changes it will reload your server.
You just use it like node, e.g.

```
nodemon server.js
```

Comment: The thing is, with that `var test`, I wouldn't know the name of the module, it's a variable (`restartModule`)

Comment: Oh yes, I'd just name it whatever.. e.g. myModule, restartModule.

Comment: yeah but it needs to be called by whatever value `restartModule` has. So it `restartModule` is equal to "name" then the var should be called "name"